# Encoded url from GET in curl function

Tags: php, curl, get, urlencode

I am passing a url from GET and making a curl request with it, but the url
 needs to be encoded.

I've tried using the proper function, urlencode, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  Perhaps I'm not initiating it correctly, not sure.

I've tried many variations of this...

```
<?php
$url=$_GET['url'];
$encoded=$urlencode['url'];
exec("curl '".$encoded."' -H
............etc
```

While testing, if I encode the url before passing through mysite.com/curl.php?url=, the curl script performs well.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: "While testing, if I encode the url before passing through mysite.com/curl.php?url=, the curl script performs well." — This is because you have misidentified the problem. The URL needs to be URL encoded so that you can read it from `$_GET`, not that you can pass it to `curl`.

Comment: So where is or what is the array `$urlencode` used in `$urlencode['url']` Or is that part of the problem, maybe a typo?

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @Quentin - This makes total sense.  Thank you for pointing this out.  So what I did after your comment was base64 encode the url prior to it being passed to mysite.com/curl.php?url=.

Then in the php script, _GET was able to grab the base64 which I could then decode and pass in to my curl.

Thank you very much for helping.  I am novice as you can see.

Comment: @MiguelGuerrero — Why base64 encode it? That just means you have to go to extra effort to base64 decode it. URL encode it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution to obtain the encoded URL from GET in the curl function:

```
$url=$_GET['url'];
$encoded=urlencode($url);
```